# Unable to show video in camera roll after trimming

Tags: swift, swift3, avfoundation, phphotolibrary, ios10.3

I'm developing video player in which I have trimming functionality. I am using ABVideoRangeSlider for that. Whenever I try to trim and save video I'm getting `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"` this error.
Here is my code snippet

```
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let track = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID:Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    try! track.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(startTimeForCurrentSlice, endTimeForCurrentSlice), of: asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as AVAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String
    let videoPathToSave = documentsDirectory.appending("mergeVideo-\(arc4random()%1000)-d.mp4")
    let videoURLToSave = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPathToSave)

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: videoURLToSave as URL)
    }) { saved, error in
        if saved {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Error: \(String(describing: error!))")
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Before saving to camera roll You need to export your `AVMutableComposition` with `AVAssetExportSession` or with `AVAssetWriter`, and after that You can save it to camera roll.

Checkout [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/94404/play-record-merge-videos-ios-swift) tutorial for `AVAssetExportSession` usage. For saving to camera roll it uses `ALAssetsLibrary`, but You can save it with `Photos`.